# Rails nested attributes with Ckeditor and Cocoon additional rich text editors don't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, cocoon-gem

I have a nested attributes form that uses the [Ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem and Simple form to build a form with multiple Rich text editors. One text editor for the `Body` and one for the `Footer`.

[image]

The relationship is `body has many footers`

I want to let users add as many footers as they want. To implement this I am using the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).
When a user clicks `Add additional footer` a form is given the problem is it is not a `Ckeditor rich text editor` just a regular form.

[image]

*Form*

```
= f.simple_fields_for :footers do |footer|
  = render 'footer_fields', f: footer
.links
  = link_to_add_association 'Add Additional Footer', f, :footers
```

*Partial*

```
  = f.input :content, label: 'Footer', as: :rich_text_mergefields, input_html: {class: 'span12'}
```

Is there anyway to add `Ckeditor` text areas on the fly with Cocoon or any way else?

Comment: I know too little of CkEditor, but theoretically you should be using the [callbacks in cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items), so `after-insert` you call the js to enable the CkEditor (if CkEditor allows this).

Comment: @nathanvda thanks for pointing me in the right direction. See below for the final implementation

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing the following, hope it helps someone in the future.

```
= f.input :content, label: 'Footer', as: :rich_text_mergefields, input_html: { class: 'span12 footer-field'}


$('#owner').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(_, element) {
   id = $(element).index() + '_footer'
   text_area = $(element[0]).find('.footer-field').attr('id', id);
   config = $(element[0]).find('.footer-field').data('ckeditorOptions');
   CKEDITOR.replace(id, config);
});
```